# how to open JQuery TreeTable at level one

Tags: javascript

expanding JQuery tree table at level one on page load.

when initial state of tree table "collapsed" then it collapse all and only parent showing, but I want to expand at level 1

```
$("#Grid").treetable({ expandable: true, initialState: "collapsed" });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#Grid").treetable({
  expandAll: true,
   inherited
});
```

Comment: it's expand all the parent child hierarchical tree,my question Dhruvin Sukhadiya is to open at level one only.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#Grid").treetable({ expandable: true, initialState: "collapsed" });
            <script>